# Adding a sub customer for quickbooks online php

Tags: php, quickbooks-online

I can't seem to get this to work:

I have a parent company called

"XYZ Parent Company"

and a sub company called

"XYZ sub Company"

The Parent company exists in quickbooks already.  I need to add the sub company with the parent know.  I try this and it does not add the child only makes new customer.  I am sure I am missing two things but I can't find what???

```
include 'blah blah directoty/example_app_ipp_v3/config.php';


// Set up the IPP instance
$IPP = new QuickBooks_IPP($dsn);

// Get our OAuth credentials from the database
$creds = $IntuitAnywhere->load($the_username, $the_tenant);

// Tell the framework to load some data from the OAuth store
$IPP->authMode(
QuickBooks_IPP::AUTHMODE_OAUTH, 
$the_username, 
$creds);

// Print the credentials we're using
//print_r($creds);

// This is our current realm
$realm = $creds['qb_realm'];

// Load the OAuth information from the database
if ($Context = $IPP->context())
{
// Set the IPP version to v3 
$IPP->version(QuickBooks_IPP_IDS::VERSION_3);

$CustomerService = new QuickBooks_IPP_Service_Customer();



 $Customer = new QuickBooks_IPP_Object_Customer();

 $Customer->setName('99999');

 //$Customer->setPhone('860-634-1602');
 //$Customer->setEmail('keith@uglyslug.com');
 $Customer->setCompanyName('XYZ Sub Company Name');
 $Customer->setDisplayName('XYZ Sub Company Name');
 $Customer->setFirstName('Bill');
 $Customer->setLastName('Gates');

 // Set the parent of the customer
 $Customer->setParentFullName('XYZ Existing Parent Company Name');
```

Answer (score 2):

This is incorrect:

```
// Set the parent of the customer
$Customer->setParentFullName('XYZ Existing Parent Company Name');
```

Per the QuickBooks API docs (http://developer.intuit.com/) you must specify *the parent Id value* to add a sub-customer underneath the parent customer. You *can not* specify the `FullName` (`FullName` isn't even a valid field name for the REST APIs, not sure where you got that from...).

You should be specifying:

```
$Customer->setParentRef(1234);
```

Where `1234` is the `Id` of the parent customer.

If you don't know the `Id` of the parent customer, you can query it like this:

```
$customers = $CustomerService->query($Context, $realm, "SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE FullyQualifiedName = 'your parent customer name here');
$Id = $customers[0]->getId();
```